# ASP.NET 5 Beta7 doesn't work anymore on Azure WebSites

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET 5 (vNext) application, just migrating from beta5 to beta7, and from dnx451 to dnx46, and I can't get it working.
My other app, works just well after the migration, I don't see any differences in that one, but I'm getting all the time following error after publishing it:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'.

System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)


System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)


System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)


Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<CreateMetadataFileReference>b__0(String _)


System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)


Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService.CreateMetadataFileReference(String path)
```

I tried several ways of publishing, I created a new fresh WebSite, still the same - only way to get it working is to comment out following piece in Startup.cs:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            //default
            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                    );
            routes.MapRoute(
                      name: "overrideRoute",
                      template: "{*url}",
                      defaults: new { action = "Index", controller = "Home" }
                      );
            //web api
            routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "apiRoute",
                  template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{bizObject}/{id?}"
                  );
        });
```

Without above, I can write

```
            app.Run(async context =>
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("test");
            });
```

and it works, but obviously I need MVC, and my other similar app works just as expected.

Any hints?

Comment: Looks like something is referencing .NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll which isn't there.  Check your references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. You can follow the bug here https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1675

Basically @Dijkgraaf is correct. The whole facades folder (`.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\`) is missing and there is nothing you can do on your end to fix that. Azure has to add that folder for builds targeting 4.6 to work. If you can, you might try to downgrade to `dnx451` and see if that works for you for now until the bug above is resolved. If you have a hard dependency on `dnx46` then unfortunately you'll just have to wait.